# Infinite $digest Loop - ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting an error `Infinite $digest Loop` while trying to loop through the following ng-repeat.

```
<select ng-options="item.QuoteId as item.Quote for item in smallGroup.getQuotesByRating(control.vlcSI['recSet']) track by $index">
    <option value="">Select Quote</option>
</select>
```

I have the following JS function :

```
          function getQuotesByRating(quotes){
                var quoteList = [];
                if(typeof quotes != 'undefined' && quotes.length > 0){
                    quotes.map(function(item){
                        if(item.RatingType == 'Member & Composite'){
                            item.Quote =  item.Quote + ' : Member Rated'
                            quoteList.push(item);
                            item.Quote =  item.Quote + ' : Composite Rated'
                            quoteList.push(item);
                        }
                        else{
                            item.Quote =  item.Quote + ' : ' + item.RatingType
                            quoteList.push(item);
                        }
                    });
                    return quoteList;
                }
                return quotes;
          }
```

What would be the possible solution for this situation?

Comment: How often is `control.vlcSI['recSet']` being updated? If the latter changes frequently, that could be the cause.

Comment: Technically once the page loads `control.vlcSI['recSet']` do not get updated. I do have a ng-if condition to check the length of it.

Comment: Oops, I missed it on my first read. Fairly certain the infinite `$digest` is due to the `quoteList` that potentially gets returned. Angular tries to compare `quotes` with `quoteList` (by reference). Since they point to two different arrays (although they reference the same items inside), Angular keeps triggering `$digest` because it is waiting for the values to stabilise (i.e. equal each other). Possible fix: bind the results of each `smallGroup.getQuotesByRating` to another model and have the `ng-repeat` iterate on that instead.